# finding the spark master in dse 5.0.3

Tags: apache-spark, datastax-enterprise

The Cassandra table dse_system.real_leaders used to be populated with the Spark master ip address.  This does not seem to be the case with dse 5.0.3.  Is there a new way to find the master through a Cassandra query?  Perhaps my dse environment is not configured correctly to populate the real_leaders table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try the following `cqlsh> call DseClientTool.getSparkMasterAddress () ;`

Answer (score 1):

**dse client-tool spark leader-address**

This will get you the randomly elected master for DSE.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the spark master in DSE by executing following command

```
dsetool sparkmaster
```